# Get IP from MAC in Lan. Using kivy on Android

Tags: android, ip, kivy, mac-address

I want to build a kivy app for my android phone that can connect to another device (ESP8266 or RaspberryPi) which is in the same network as the android phone.

I got the Mac of the device and now want to run a scan that returns the current IP (Which is different from time to time due to DHCP) address of that device with this mac.

I read a lot about this problem an the following pice of code works on my Linux machine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from scapy.all import arping
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout



class App(App):

    def build(self):
        self.ti = TextInput(text='8c:cf:7c:18:75:63')
        self.btn = Button(on_press=self.getIP, text='Scan')
        self.label = Label(text='IP zu obiger Mac:\n')
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.layout.add_widget(self.ti)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.label)
        return self.layout

    def getIP(self, *args):
        mac = self.ti.text
        ans, unans = arping('192.168.0.*')
        for s, r in ans.res:
            line = r.sprintf("%Ether.src%  %ARP.psrc%").split()
            m = line[0]
            ip = line[1]
            if m.lower() == mac.lower():
                self.label.text = self.label.text + ip

if __name__=='__main__':
    App().run()
```

As you see I am importing scapy. To run correctly the script has to be run with sudo. Because of that I get an socketerror on my phone saying permission denied. This is the same error I get on my linux machine when I do not run the script with sudo.

Is there a solution to get such a portscanner working on android with kivy?
(I tried nmap for python yet wich also does not work together with kivy)

I do not want to use a static IP!

Thanks for replies!

Sebastian